# ImageIO.read expression that worked fine suddenly stopped doing so

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, javax.imageio

I am currently trying to load a spritesheet for a small game I am working on. The issue is that piece of code here:

```
private void load(){
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Sprite.class.getResource(path));
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`ImageIO.read()` always returns `null`. It also doesn't throw any exceptions. Obviously, I get a error on the next line as I call `image.getWidth()` as image is `null`.

What really bothers me is that the same piece of code worked completely fine 10 minutes ago. I haven't changed anything but a value that doesn't affect the reading process at all; even changing it back wouldn't do anything.

Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: You should always check you return value of `ImageIO.read`, since a null return value is normal return value when the image couldn't be decoded http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is here:

```
Sprite.class.getResource(path)
```

You can write this line out and check that is your path right or not.
This problem occurs when your file path is not true. Check your file path by using this line of code:

```
System.out.println(Sprite.class.getResource(path));
```

then you can find the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that helped me, although it wasn't the Problem. The path is indeed correct, but through following that hint I discovered that the Image file was corrupt - I have no idea how that happened, but I resolved it :)